# Working with two parallel arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to finish an assignment for my c++ class. I am not looking for the assignment to be completed for me but I have reached an impasse, and my professor isn't the best at replying to emails. She has a lot going on so it's understandable.

I am creating a program to read data from an input file. The data includes an employees last name, number of hours worked, and pay rate per hour. My problem is that I need this information placed into two parallel arrays. If I can figure out how to do so I can finish the assignment on my own, but I have literally searched with google, and watched every video I could find but to no avail.

```
Here is the input data:
Smith     40  10.00
Jackson   25  8.00
Hill      35  10.00
Withers   28  7.25
Mills     32  7.55
Myers     50  10.25
Johnson   45  10.50
Mcclure   38  9.50
Miller    42  8.75
Mullins   40  10.75
```

UPDATE: I have edited my code and am getting close to the results I need to continue onto the next step of my project. I have edited how I read and initialize the data from file I have. However between my columns I get a strange sequence of numbers.

```
Smith 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
40 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
10.00 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
Jackson 
-9.25596e+61 
  7.25 
-9.25596e+61 
25 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
8.00 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
Hill 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
35  
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
10.00 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61 
-9.25596e+61
```

Follows is my revised code.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int NOFROWS = 10;
const int NOFCOLS = 3;

void readFile(ifstream& infile, string X[], double y[][NOFCOLS]);
void print(ifstream&infile,ofstream& outfile, string x[], double y[] [NOFCOLS]);

int main()
{

//variables

string names[20];
double wages[NOFROWS][NOFCOLS];
ifstream incode;
ofstream outcode;
incode.open("employeeinformation.txt");
outcode.open("results.txt");
if (!incode)
{
    cout << "No data" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;           //if loop to terminate program if unable to open    file
}
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;
readFile(incode, names, wages);  //calls function readFile
print(incode,outcode, names, wages);

incode.close();
outcode.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}


//Function to read file and input information into array.
void readFile(ifstream& infile, string x[], double y[][NOFCOLS])
{
//local variables, used as counters for while loop. 
int r = 0;
int c = 0;

for (r = 0; r < NOFROWS; r++)
    infile >> x[r]; // gets information from file for position 
infile >> y[r][c];
//r++; //counter to increase position value 
for (c = 0; c < NOFCOLS; c++)
{
    infile >> y[c][r];
}
```

}

```
void print(ifstream&infile, ofstream& outfile, string x[], double y[]         [NOFCOLS])
{
cout << setw(10) << "Names" << setw(10) << "hours" << setw(10) <<        "wages";
for (int r = 0; r < NOFROWS; r++) {
    outfile << x[r] << " " << endl;
    for (int c = 0; c < NOFCOLS; c++)
    {
        outfile << setw(10) << y[r][c] << " " << endl;



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you open the file once, but attempt to read its contents twice.

```
readFile(incode, names);  // reads incode until all data is read
readFile2(incode, wages); // reads from the same incode, that has all data already expended
```

Try to for example `close` and `open` the file or move the read pointer to the begining before the second call, or better yet refactor the code for RAII file management.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would simply have a single `parseFile()` function which reads one line at a time and populates the names, hours and wages as it goes.

```
while (inFile) {
    inFile >> names[i] >> hours[i] >> wages[i];
    i++;
}
```

With your current setup (`readFile()` followed by `readFile2()`), your `readFile()` function is reading to the end of the file.  You will need to seek back to the beginning of the file before calling `readFile2()`, or it will continue trying to read from the end of the file.

```
inFile.clear();
inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you over the line, and good luck with the assignment!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've tried using a single while(infile) but the problem is I can only use two arrays, one for the names and one for the hours and wages.